# Character encoding on Websphere Portal

Tags: character-encoding, websphere-portal

How can I check the character encoding set on My Websphere Portal server? I mean after logging into the console, where do I go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that you want to enable "UTF-8", for example, then:

- On the Application Server page, click on the name of the server that you want it to be UTF-8 enabled.
- On the settings page for the selected application server, click **Process Definition**.
- On the Process Definition page, click **Java Virtual Machine**.
- On the Java Virtual Machine page, specify **-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8** for **Generic JVM Arguments** and click OK.
- Click Save on the console taskbar.
- Restart the application server.

This can work for any Character Encoding.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to "Administration/Portal Settings/Supported Markups" and click on "Show info"

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an application server or use an existing application server.
2. On the Application Server page, click on the name of the server you 
   want enabled for UTF-8.
3. On the settings page for the selected application server, click
   Process Definition.
4. On the Process Definition page, click Java Virtual Machine.
5. On the Java Virtual    Machine page, specify
   **-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8** for Generic   JVM Arguments and click OK.
6. Click Save on the console taskbar.
7. Restart the application server.

From IBM Support Website.